# SSH Tunnel with eb-cli (elastic beanstalk/aws)

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services

I am trying to follow this [guide](https://medium.com/@michalisantoniou6/connect-to-an-aws-rds-using-an-ssh-tunnel-22f3bd597924) to setup a ssh tunnel to my rds database.

In particular this command:

```
ssh -N -L localPort:rdsHost:remotePort user@remoteHost -i ~/path/to/key
```

However, I am using aws-elastic-beanstalk with the eb-cli.

The eb cli provides `eb -ssh` to connect via ssh to an instance.

```
eb ssh -e '-N -L localPort:rdsHost:remotePort'
```

from the eb documentation:

> -e CUSTOM, --custom CUSTOM
>                           Specify an SSH command to use instead of 'ssh -i
>                           keyfile'. Do not include the remote user and hostname.

However, this only yields the following output and terminates instead of creating a tunnel.

```
INFO: Attempting to open port 22.
INFO: SSH port 22 open.
INFO: Running -N -L localPort:rdsHost:remotePort ec2-user@ip-of-instance
```

Is it possible to create a tunnel with the eb-cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

As you've seen, the documentation is not very clear about it, but when you use the `-e` or `--custom` flag, you must *also* provide the `-i` flag to the underlying `ssh` command or it won't use the right key.

So the full command would look like this (e.g. to tunnel port 9229):

```
   eb ssh --custom 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/keyfile.pem -L 9229:localhost:9229'
```

Comment: First I wondered because it also opens a terminal in the instance.. but it works perfectly fine. Thank you very much!